# PHP read large excel file error

Tags: internal-server-error, phpexcelreader

I'm trying to create a application for load and read a large excel file (more than 60,000 rows) using PHPExcel library. I am getting internal server. It works fine upto 600 rows. But its not working for large files. Please help.

Or any other php library available to load large files.

set_time_limit(36000);

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);   

##$top_records is a boolean set to get just the header and the first data row (( For field Mapping))        

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . SITE_PATH . '/core/extLib/Excel/Classes/');

require_once (SITE_PATH . '/core/extLib/Excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

include (SITE_PATH . '/core/extLib/Excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder1( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() );
$inputFileName = $file;

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, we could spend some time guessing what's happening or what your code is doing, or you could __post some code__ and __error messages__ and a decent description of the problem

Comment: Most-likely you are exceeding memory or script timeout limits. The Excel format is not very efficient, and neither are the PHP libraries for it.

Comment: Thanks @HoboSapiens . Please check above code

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I tried by changing memory limit and script time out too.

Answer (score 1):

I have same your problem. The problem occur when work on this line

`$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PHPExcel is not meant to handle very large files. Changing the memory limit or time limit is at best a temporary fix but you will have the same problem with bigger files.

I can suggest you taking a look at [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) instead. It works great for your use case!

Answer (score 0):

Increase memory limit. (eg: `ini_set('memory_limit', '512'`) ),

Or use chunk instead. [link](http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php)